Unexpected output when using DateFormat
Wrong flutter DateFormat result with DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);
DateFormat('HH:mm:ss.SSS').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0))

Returns 02:00:00.000, but isn't it supposed to return 00:00:00.000?

What timezone are you in?

The epoch timestamp would be 00:00:00.000 only in GMT/UTC time zone. If you are formatting the date while being in a different time zone, of course you get the hours shown accordingly.
